# Can I assign function based on the condition in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, chaining

I have two similar function as below;

For last element function;

```
function last () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        left:'-1200',
        opacity:0
    },500, function(){
        $this
        .addClass('hide')
        .next()
        .removeClass('hide').animate({
            left:'0',
            opacity:1
        },500)
    });
}
```

For first element function;

```
function first () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        left:'1200',
        opacity:0
    },500, function(){
        $this
        .addClass('hide')
        .prev()
        .removeClass('hide').animate({
            left:'0',
            opacity:1
        },500)
    });
}
```

they are similar and I want to combine them as one function, as below;

```
function steps (pos) { /* -- Dif-1 -- */
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        left:pos==='next'&& '-'+'1200', /* -- Dif-2 -- */
        opacity:0
    },500, function(){
        $this
        .addClass('hide')
            pos==='next' ? next() : prev()  /* -- Dif-3 -- */
        .removeClass('hide').animate({
            left:'0',
            opacity:1
        },500)
    });    
}
```

I want to determine function next() or prev() according to pos variable (pos==='next' ? next() : prev() ). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in your `left` property can be done using a simple ternary operator:

```
left: pos==='next' ? -1200 : 1200
```

And you can continue chaining your methods if you use bracket notation to call `prev()` or `next()`:

```
$this.addClass('hide')
[pos==='next' ? "next" : "prev"]()
.removeClass('hide').animate({
```

Or, assuming `pos` will always be either `next` or `prev`, simply use `[pos]()`:

```
function steps (pos) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        left:pos==='next' ? -1200 : 1200,
        opacity:0
    },500, function(){
        $this
        .addClass('hide')[pos]()
        .removeClass('hide').animate({
            left:'0',
            opacity:1
        },500)
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You gave this a great shot.  Here is how I would achieve your goal:

```
function steps (pos) { /* -- Dif-1 -- */
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.animate({
      left:(pos==='next'?-1:1) * 1200, /* -- Dif-2 -- */
      opacity:0
  },500, function(){
      var elt = $this.addClass('hide');
      var elt2 = (pos==='next' ? elt.next() : elt.prev());  /* -- Dif-3 -- */
      elt2.removeClass('hide').animate({
          left:'0',
          opacity:1
      },500);
  });    
}
```

There are other ways, ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.. Include jquery before testing. Ofcourse you can optimize this code . .this is just to show the alternate approach..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function steps (elem, pos) { /* -- Dif-1 -- */
    var $this = $(elem);

    var obj = $this.animate({
        left: (pos == 'next') ? -1200 : 1200, /* -- Dif-2 -- */
        opacity:0
    },500, function(){
        $this
        .addClass('hide');
    });

    if (pos == 'next')
        obj.next();
    else
        obj.prev();


    obj.removeClass('hide').animate({
        left:'0',
        opacity:1
    },500)

}




</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">Test Div</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        steps($("#test"), "prev");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `next()` and `prev()` return an element, they do not update the `obj` object directly.  I think you forgot to update `obj` by assignment.

Comment: yes you are right .. we should update the obj variable like this obj = obj.next();